# How to use Hazelcast REST Client to retrieve Entry from a Map where key is a customized class?

Tags: hazelcast

As per link http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.5/manual/html/restclient.html

Hazelcast provides a REST interface, i.e. it provides an HTTP service in each node so that you can access your map using HTTP protocol. If you want to retrieve an entry, you can use a GET call.

For Example: `http://10.20.17.1:5701/hazelcast/rest/maps/mapName/key1.`

But what if my key is a Java custom object like:

```
public class RuleCacheKey implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4469783255830688852L;
    private int id;
    private String type;
}
```

Is there a way to retrieve all keys in the map using REST API?

Comment: Hi, did you get any solution here? I am also trying to do the same thing but in rest get api. My map values are custom objects which I want to access via REST.

Comment: I have used client console with small changes to get keys for custom classes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43487914/getting-serializationexception-on-hazelcast-management-center-console-with-custo

Answer (score 0):

The REST API is in general only considered to be like a "last resort" type of access interface (for languages that do not have a native client, like PHP), since it'll not perform as good as native clients. On the other hand the built-in REST API only supports string or binary keys. That said it would be possible to build it, however it'll be much more complicated (you would have to serialize upfront and make sure, it'll be the same serialization as with Hazelcast).

You're probably better of to use the native Hazelcast client in your app or to build your own, specific REST API (webservice) to access the cluster information. The way to go most probably depends on your exact use case.